# Navigate from UITextField to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have 1 problem when i click button "Next" of keypard to move cursor from TextField to TextView

The first ,all is ok. But in the second , the cursor jump into the line second of textView and then every time i click Next from TextField, the cursor in TextView will down one line more.

Comment: What "next" are you talking about?

Comment: hi j0k : i set the "Return" key become "Next" key on keypard of TextField

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the question seems to be an intresting one. In most of the cases, the cursor jump is from one **TextField** to another **TextField**. Here you need to jump the editing from one **TextField** to another **TextView**, so you can try this method:

First create outlets for your textView and TextField, in your `viewcontroller.h`, say

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

and `viewcontroller.m` do this:

```
 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {      
        if(textField isFirstResponder)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [textView becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

**EDIT :** 
 If the method don't work as expected, this will make the change:
'

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField isFirstResponder)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [textview performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

(To be honest, I have no idea how this performSelector with 0 delay solved the issue, but the solution worked for the OP .Thanks Luong Anh for the comment.)

Comment: return `YES`. true is so un-cocoa like :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan Done..and feel free to edit. Helpful improvisations are always appreciated :-)

Comment: thank MicRO , i tried to do it the same but result doesn't change. 
One friend told me change 1 one row and it success,but i still dont know how result is OK 

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {      
        if(textField isFirstResponder)
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            [textview performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

Comment: @LuongAnh Well, I didn't test my code and its output..and glad to know that the delay played the trick..with your permission may I improve the answer with your tip? So that it can help any future vistors..or you can edit my answer with the same. What do you think?

Comment: Thank MicRO so much <br/>
because i had to go out so i couldn't answer you.<br/>

i'm glad for editing your coment! i hope it can help any future vistors. <br/>
Dear ^^

Comment: @MicRO: i want to like or upvote but i has just joined website so i dont know something
i will tried to capture all information. thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

you only need to put `[yourtextView becomeFirstResponder];`
 in your `textFieldShouldReturn` method.